# How to capture the LUIS JSON response to a user's input using LUIS recognizer in node js

Tags: node.js, azure-language-understanding

```
// Assigning the published LUIS app URL which is obtained after training the related utterances in LUIS.

LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey+'/&verbose=true&q= /';

console.log(LuisModelUrl);

//recognizing the intents using LUIS Recognizer
var recognizerData = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);

console.log("------------"+JSON.stringify(recognizerData.intents));
```

can somebody guide on how to do this using node js.

Comment: Bot framework 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to perform one-time calls to LUIS instead of plugging the LuisRecognizer into a bot, LuisRecognizer has a static [`recognize`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.luisrecognizer.html#recognize-1) method that you can use to call your LUIS model.

```
LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId +
    '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey+'/&verbose=true&q= /'

// Callback that console logs the intents
function printData (err, intents, entities) {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }
    console.log("------------"+ JSON.stringify(intents))
}

//recognizing the intents using LUIS Recognizer
builder.LuisRecognizer.recognize('I love chairs', LuisModelUrl, printData)
```